# How to syncing permissions from lightswitch dev to production

Tags: permissions, visual-studio-lightswitch

I need to add a permission to an existing application.  In development Ive added the permission along with some logic to restrict access to a screen.  Tested and working.

My question is how do I sync the new permission to the production deployment?

Ive tried adding it manually with a simple insert statement, but it does not work.  In the administration section on the deployed production site there is no way I can find to add a new permission.

Please help!

Comment: firstly is this for a HTML Client project? and if yes, do you also have a desktop client added to the project?

Comment: Yeah its for an html client project.  No desktop client is in the project.